# Are 10k rep users able to see deleted answers in my profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, deleted-answers

Users with 10k reputation have the priviledge to see deleted answers in a Question.

If I was a 10k+ rep user, and I went to someones profile description, would I be able to still see his deleted answers in the Answer Listings ??

Thanks for your time. I hope the question is inline with the rules, and that I am clear. It is my first time posting in meta so I hope I got the tags correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only diamond moderators are able to see deleted posts in your profile. 10k users can see deleted questions and answers when they run across them, but they cannot locate them through your profile.

Answer (score 2):

I have deleted [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610239/arriving-late-to-a-daily-stand-up-meeting/3610329#3610329) and I don't see it in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413501/ladislav-mrnka) (should be first as top voted). So I think you can't.