# Users see different a value for "Answers" than the owner of the profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

In ServerFault chat, we were playing around figuring out rep/answer for some of the top users. Chopper3 was in the room and I posted what I thought his rep per answer should be by simply dividing rep by questions answered. He got a different number. After figuring out that we can both do basic math, we realized that he sees a different number for `Answers` on his own profile than we do. The first screen cap is mine, the second is his.

Another user, (Iain), confirmed that he sees what I see on Chopper3's profile. When Iain and I inspect each other's profiles, we see the expected results with no discrepancy. Does this have something to do with Chopper3 being a diamond mod?

What's the cause for this discrepancy? The screen caps were taken a few seconds apart.

[image: Me]

[image: Him]

Comment: I see 2024 as well. Perhaps his view includes deleted answers?

Comment: I'd guess that being a mod, his deleted answers could be shown in his view (and not in mere mortal views).

Comment: @Mat has it. Moderators see deleted questions and answers in the profile lists. This will be the cause of the discrepancy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mods can see deleted answers in profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77432/are-10k-rep-users-able-to-see-deleted-answers-in-my-profile/77433#77433), which may accounts for why [chopper3](https://serverfault.com/users/1435/chopper3) sees more answers than us plebs do.

Answer (score 0):

Has he deleted any of his answers? If so, I think they will show when he views his own profile.

<strike>Nevermind, I just deleted this answer and that's not the cause; I don't see it in my own profile.</strike> Okay, I guess that really was the issue as Shawn said.